# @AuthenticationPrincipal UserModel user is always Null. I tried many solution methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

There is a controller whose task is to return the user profile to me using the REST API. Code further:

```java
@PostMapping("/me")
public UserProfileResponse getUserProfile(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserAuthenticationPrincipalModel user ) {
    return userProfileService.getUserProfile(user.getUserId());
}
```

I created a model for the User entity. The entity class is created as:

```java
public class User implements UserDetails { ... }
```

The model has the following structure:

```java
public class UserAuthenticationPrincipalModel extends User {
    private String userId;
    private String avatarUrl;

    public UserAuthenticationPrincipalModel(***.********.entity.User user) {
        super(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), user.isAccountNonExpired(),
                user.isCredentialsNonExpired(), user.isAccountNonLocked(), user.getAuthorities());
        this.userId = user.getUserId();
        this.avatarUrl = user.getUserPic();
    }
// + equals and hashCode
}
```

In the model, the data that I will ever (or so far plan so) to pull from the AuthPrincipal an authorized user. According to the statement of work, I can’t use the default Principal, I haven’t even tried it. Implementation of UserDetailsService:

```java
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl extends AbstractMySQLService<User, String, UserRepository> implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(final UserRepository userRepository, final UserRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserAuthenticationPrincipalModel loadUserByUsername(final String email) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or user not e: " + email);
        }

        return new UserAuthenticationPrincipalModel(user);
    }
}
```

**Error:** Null always flies into methods. Made a lot of additions, which are recommended on the Baeldang and this stack - nothing :(

Please, write a comment, if I should add some more information.

---

UPD 1:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/ca/**").hasRole("COMPANY_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/d/**").hasRole("DRIVER")
                .antMatchers("/u/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/sign_up", "/oauth/token", "/swagger-ui.html", "/resources").permitAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give you a few pointers of how to approach this issue.

1. Ensure you are using `org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal` instead of `@org.springframework.security.web.bind.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal` (Both should work but just pre-caution because the later is deprecated)
2. Now the issue is to isolate the problem to **ONE** of the following areas so you can concentrate there:

   1. Your `UserDetailsServiceImpl` is not used
   2. Something wrong with `getUserProfile` method with `@AuthenticationPrincipal`
   3. user is not associated with a logged in session.
3. To identify that, replace your `public UserProfileResponse getUserProfile` method with the following:
   [Do not change anything else]

```
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @PostMapping("/me")
    public void getUserProfile(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails user ) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println("principal : " + authentication.getPrincipal());
        System.out.println("Implementing class of UserDetails: " + authentication.getPrincipal().getClass());
        System.out.println("Implementing class of UserDetailsService: " + userDetailsService.getClass());
    }
```

4. Check the logs and it will tell you where the problem is and if you can't figure out from it, you can post the outcome here for more help

> **Update:** Answers for point 4 given as below in comments.
>
> - principal : anonymousUser
> - Implementing class of UserDetails : class java.lang.String
> - Implementing class of UserDetailsService : class

5. Conclusion : endpoint is not protected and user accessing without logging in
6. Solution : Protect the endpoint by replacing `.antMatchers("/u/**").authenticated()` with `.antMatchers("/api/u/**").authenticated()`

Comment: 1. I use correct annotation. 2-3. Result: `Implementing class of UserDetails:class java.lang.String
Implementing class of UserDetailsService:class ua.cargo_pointer.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl` 4. So, as I understood, problem in the 1st point. (updated!)

Comment: Yes. `null` and `principlaanonymousUser`.

Comment: I have this annotation in head of class: `@RequestMapping("/api/u")`. In Postman i write new POST: `http://localhost:8081/api/u/me`

Comment: New response! `{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-20T18:28:27.792+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/api/u/me"
}` UPDATED: Yes, authorized through Auth in Postman.

Comment: well. you know your endpoint is now protected and also you know your original getProfile method is correct as well your user detail service is used. Now you need to figure out the separate issue of access denied. It may be your username and password are wrong or something else. Put a breakpoint for line ```UserDetails loadedUser = this.getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);``` in class ```
```org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider```  , debug and see if your username and password matches